# Getting Images To Show In Google Results

Tags: google

I'm wondering if it's possible to get Google to show an image next to a search result without using the `og:video` meta tag. I've only ever seen websites using said tag to get Google to show images next to search results. The problem, however, is that my site's content provides no swf to view the content on the site.

Currently my pages have pretty much every other applicable open graph meta tag including `og:image`. I'm using Google's service to test the search result: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Are you talking about [displaying Google+ image profile](http://www.jeremymorgan.com/blog/seo/how-to-display-your-profile-picture-in-google-search-results/) next to your result?

Comment: What is the question about?

Comment: No, with open graph you can have a thumbnail for a video show. I'm curious as to if there's a way to have a thumbnail show for other media types.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question but i never find such listing who shows image same as it displaying video in organic SERP.

As of now, once can get such listing by incorporating Google+ profile using author tag.